# Multiple undefined references when trying to build PyQT4 from the sources

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pyqt4

Lots of these lines

```
/home/chaouche/DOWNLOADS/PYTHON/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.10.4/qpy/QtCore/qpycore_chimera_signature.cpp:54: undefined reference to `PyCapsule_New'
../qpy/QtCore/libqpycore.a(qpycore_chimera_signature.o): In function `Signature_delete':
/home/chaouche/DOWNLOADS/PYTHON/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.10.4/qpy/QtCore/qpycore_chimera_signature.cpp:110: undefined reference to `PyCapsule_GetPointer'
../qpy/QtCore/libqpycore.a(qpycore_chimera_storage.o): In function `Chimera::Storage::toPyObject() const':
/home/chaouche/DOWNLOADS/PYTHON/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.10.4/qpy/QtCore/qpycore_chimera_storage.cpp:113: undefined reference to `_Py_NoneStruct'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libQtCore.so] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/chaouche/DOWNLOADS/PYTHON/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.10.4/QtCore'
make: *** [sub-QtCore-make_default-ordered] Error 2
root@karabeela /home/chaouche/DOWNLOADS/PYTHON/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.10.4 #
```

When I tried to install pyqt4 from sources.

I have libqt4-devel and libpython-devel installed. I also have installed sip. Do I need anything else ?

Comment: Run configure.py with the `--verbose` flag set. If that doesn't make it clear what is wrong, post the output here.

Comment: cfgtest_QAxContainer.cpp:1:23: fatal error: qaxobject.h: No such file or directory 
compilation terminated.
make: *** [cfgtest_QAxContainer.o] Error 1

Comment: It seems this has to do with ActiveX, although I'm building on Linux. But configure-ng.py continues after this error, it doesn't seem to be critical for the rest of the installation, or is it ? (here's full output http://pastie.org/8975639

Comment: It's got nothing to do with ActiveX: it is normal for that to fail on Linux. There doesn't seem to be any other obvious errors in the configure log. Since all the errors appear ro refer to python itself, there must be some missing headers/libs somewhere. Are you sure you've installed all the necessary dev packages for the version of python you're compiling against? (I also see that you're using a snapshot of sip - is there any particular reason for that?)

Comment: I usually install snapshots, I'm not comfortable with dev repositories (stability ?)

Comment: The snapshots definitely _aren't_ stable. They are meant for testing purposes only. Unless you are trying to fix a specific bug, you should stick with the [latest stable version](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download).

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know that. I thought they were like svn tags... Thanks for the enlightening.

Comment: sip was already installed in my system. I can't uninstall it because it is critical for major parts of the system like the KDE Desktop. Can't I compile PyQt with the already installed sip ? also, the sip errors aren't from the already installed sip but from the sip subdirectory which is inside PyQt itself, and I downloaded a stable version of PyQt.

Comment: It would probably be better to ask this sort of question on the [pyqt mailing list](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt). Make sure you state the specific versions of sip and pyqt you are using, and include any relevant output.

Comment: Sure, I've already sent an email like 24 hours ago. It should be in the moderation queue.